# Button Layout Issues - JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to create an application with a big area of text in the center with a row of 5 buttons on the bottom.  Here is my code:

```
public TheDungeon()
{
  setTitle("InsertGameNameHere");
  setSize(750, 600);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);


  gameScreen = new JLabel();

  add(gameScreen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  setVisible(true);    

} 

private void buildButtonPanel()
{
  // Create a panel for the buttons.
  buttonPanel = new JPanel();

  // Create the buttons.
  b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
  b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
  b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
  b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
  b5 = new JButton("Button 5");

  // Add the buttons to the button panel.
  buttonPanel.add(b1);
  buttonPanel.add(b2);
  buttonPanel.add(b3);
  buttonPanel.add(b4);
  buttonPanel.add(b5);
}
```

My application won't even run. It crashes when I attempt to run it. I'm not sure what the issue is.  **My error if it helps any:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:998)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:562)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
at TheDungeon.<init>(TheDungeon.java:38)
at TheDungeon.main(TheDungeon.java:230)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:998)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:562)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
at TheDungeon.<init>(TheDungeon.java:38)
at TheDungeon.main(TheDungeon.java:230)
```

Means that you're trying to "de-reference" a null variable at line 38 of your TheDungeon class: `at TheDungeon.<init>(TheDungeon.java:38)`.

I'm guessing that this involves the buttonPanel. Do you ever call buildButtonPane() -- I don't see this call anywhere? If you don't the buttonPanel JPanel will be null.

Solution: call the method before using the JPanel. Even better, have the method **return** a JPanel which you then use.

The lesson to learn from this problem is not the specific solution, but rather how to read the NullPointerException. It will tell you which line is causing the error, and then you can check the variables on that line to see which is null, then trace back into your code and see why.

Comment: God I feel like such a noob. It worked.  Now, I have it set to ask for an input and when I add that input the buttons all gather in the top-right hand corner.  Is there a way to force the buttons to stay where they are?

Comment: @Xearta: the lesson to learn from this problem is not the specific solution, but rather how to read the NullPointerException. It will tell you which line is causing the error, and then you can check the variables on that line to see which is null, then trace back into your code and see why.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I actually didn't know how to read the errors but thanks for letting me know how to. I asked a question in the comment above.  Is there a way to fix this? As well, how do I have the method return a JPanel like you said above?

Comment: @Xearta: Your new question does not have enough information I think to be answerable. We have no idea what you are doing code-wise to cause this change in program behavior. Perhaps you should ask a new question and show us how you're doing this.